# how to create android popup window on click on item in the list view should contain same list items

Tags: android, listview, popupwindow

I have list views containing items when I click on the item I need popup window should contain same list view items. please help me

Answer (score 0):

On the click of listview items call alert dialog and just pass the arraylist of items in the dialog

Comment: what is the issue u are getting

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
             builder.setTitle("Select Items");
             builder.setItems(itemsList1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     dialog.cancel();

                 }
             });
             AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
             alert.show();

Comment: but there in                                                                                                                                                            builder.setItems(itemsList1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

Comment: I don't understand , u are not able to call this code on click of listview item

Comment: can i ping u in chat

Comment: its difficult to say here

Comment: I have send u invite pls except